# Ruby code to look for a specific file,and rename it,doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, linux

I am trying to generate thumbnails with Ruby,on a linux machine.

The process,includes determining which of the 5 thumbnails,already generated,is the most meaningful(by meaningful,here,i meant to pick the one with the highest size,since a bigger size means more details).

Afterwards i went to rename the file having the biggest size into a generic name in order to use it later.The code doesn't seem to be working for me,and i can't understand the reason,is there any suggestions to improve it?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

For your possible needs, the variable `thumb_dir`  contains the path of the directory we are getting the thumbnails,from.

```
max = File.size("#{thumb_dir}/thumb01.jpg").to_f #
name = "thumb01.jpg"

for i in 2..5
  if max < File.size("#{thumb_dir}/thumb0'"#{i}"'.jpg" ).to_f?
    max = File.size("#{thumb_dir}/thumb0'"{i}"'.jpg"
    name = "thumb0" + "#{i}" + ".jpg"
  end
end

File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/#{name}", "thumbnail.jpg") `
```

Comment: There's some pretty gnarly syntax errors in there. Are you sure this is your code?

Comment: yes,it is mine,i am a beginner,so there will be obviously some mistakes...

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to get it to at least run without syntax errors when trying to solve a problem. There's a whole lot of chaos in that code. As with anything in programming it's important to pay attention to details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = (1..5).map {|i| File.size("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i}.jpg").to_f }.each_with_index.max[1]

File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i + 1}.jpg", "thumbnail.jpg")
```

What does it do ?

1. `(1..5).map {|i| File.size("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i}.jpg").to_f }`

We get an array of file sizes for thumb1.jpg up to thumb5.jpg

2. `array.each_with_index.max[1]`

Used to get the index of the greatest value of the array.

3. `File.rename("#{thumb_dir}/thumb#{i+1}.jpg", "thumbnail.jpg")`

Now that we know that i is the index of the greatest value in the array, then `thumb#{(i+1)}.jpg` is the file with the greatest size, so that's the one we want to replace the name of.

Comment: Thank you,this is the closest to my code,and understanding of it,it seems pretty smooth,especially with your hints.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in Ruby there's a number of useful methods in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) that make this sort of thing pretty straightforward:

```
# Expand to a list of possible thumbnail paths
thumbnails = (2..5).map { |n| '%s/thumb%02d.jpg' % [ thumb_dir, n ] }

# Find the biggest thumbnail by...
biggest_thumbnail = thumbnails.select do |path|
  # ...only dealing with those files that exist...
  File.exist?(path)
end.max_by do |path|
  # ...and looking for the one with the maximum size.
  File.size(path)
end
```

That should return the largest file if one exists. If not you get `nil`.

You can use that to rename:

```
if (biggest_thumbnail)
  File.rename(biggest_thumbnail, 'thumbnail.jpg')
end
```

You'll want to back up your original images before unleashing something like this on it that could potentially delete a bunch of files.

Comment: can you please add some comments and details to your code? i can't understand it...or if you wish,just make corrections on my code,that would be better,because i wrote it,i understand it,as i said,am a beginner.

Comment: @MrRobot Added some comments here but the real understanding comes from experimenting with this in `irb` or otherwise to see how the parts behave. Each step does a very specific thing.